# mt7601u-ap ドライバーをRaspberry Piにインストールしたい。

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Raspberry Piにmt7601uチップを搭載したwifi子機を付けて、アクセスポイントを作ろうと思ったのですが、どうやらドライバーが必要なようで、ビルドしようとしたのですが、

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ git clone https://github.com/tanaka1892/mt7601u-ap
Cloning into 'mt7601u-ap'...
remote: Counting objects: 1082, done.
remote: Total 1082 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1082
Receiving objects: 100% (1082/1082), 3.01 MiB | 229.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (577/577), done.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd mt7601u-ap/
pi@raspberrypi:~/mt7601u-ap $ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/mt7601u-ap/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/mt7601u-ap/tools'
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap/tools/bin2h
make -C /lib/modules/4.14.50-v7+/build SUBDIRS=/home/pi/mt7601u-ap/os/linux modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.14.50-v7+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
pi@raspberrypi:~/mt7601u-ap $ sudo make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/mt7601u-ap/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/mt7601u-ap/tools'
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap/tools/bin2h
make -C /lib/modules/4.14.50-v7+/build SUBDIRS=/home/pi/mt7601u-ap/os/linux modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.14.50-v7+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

という感じでエラーが表示されてしまいました。
因みに、ラズパイは最新の状態にしてあります。
助けてください。
<追記>

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/mt7601u-ap-master $ sudo make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/tools'
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/tools/bin2h
make -C /lib/modules/4.14.34-v7+/build SUBDIRS=/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.34-v7+'
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_mbss.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap.c: In function ‘APStartUp’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap.c:722:1: warning: the frame size of 1072 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
 }
 ^
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_assoc.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_auth.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_auth.c: In function ‘APPeerDeauthReqAction’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_auth.c:166:5: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     if (!PeerDeauthReqSanity(pAd, Elem->Msg, Elem->MsgLen, Addr2, &SeqNum, &Reason))
     ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_auth.c:169:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘if’
  pEntry = NULL;
  ^~~~~~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_connect.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_sanity.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_sync.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c: In function ‘HandleCounterMeasure’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c:566:5: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     if (!pEntry)
     ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c:570:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘if’
  if (IS_ENTRY_APCLI(pEntry))
  ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c: In function ‘RTMPHandleSTAKey’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c:1342:5: warning: this ‘else’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     else
     ^~~~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c:1347:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘else’
  if (pEntry->bDlsInit && !peerKeyInfo.Request) /*Benson add for big-endian 20081016 --> */
  ^~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_data.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_data.c: In function ‘APHandleRxDataFrame_Hdr_Trns’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_data.c:5213:30: error: passing argument 2 of ‘hex_dump’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  hex_dump("DataFrameHeader", pHeader, 36);
                              ^~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/include/rt_config.h:70:0,
                 from /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_data.c:33:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/include/rt_os_util.h:600:6: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘HEADER_802_11 * {aka struct _HEADER_802_11 *}’
 void hex_dump(char *str, PUCHAR pSrcBufVA, UINT SrcBufLen);
      ^~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:328: recipe for target '/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_data.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_data.o] Error 1
Makefile:1528: recipe for target '_module_/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.34-v7+'
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

<成功>

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/mt7601u-ap-master $ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/tools'
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/tools/bin2h
make -C /lib/modules/4.14.34-v7+/build SUBDIRS=/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.34-v7+'
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_mbss.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap.c: In function ‘APStartUp’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap.c:722:1: warning: the frame size of 1072 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
 }
 ^
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_assoc.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_auth.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_auth.c: In function ‘APPeerDeauthReqAction’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_auth.c:166:5: warning: this ‘i ’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     if (!PeerDeauthReqSanity(pAd, Elem->Msg, Elem->MsgLen, Addr2, &SeqNum, &Reason))
     ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_auth.c:169:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘if’
  pEntry = NULL;
  ^~~~~~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_connect.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_sanity.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_sync.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c: In function ‘HandleCounterMeasure’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c:566:5: warning: this ‘if ’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     if (!pEntry)
     ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c:570:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘if’
  if (IS_ENTRY_APCLI(pEntry))
  ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c: In function ‘RTMPHandleSTAKey’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c:1342:5: warning: this ‘else’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     else
     ^~~~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_wpa.c:1347:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘els ’
  if (pEntry->bDlsInit && !peerKeyInfo.Request) /*Benson add for big-endian 20081016 --> */
  ^~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_data.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_autoChSel.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_qload.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_cfg.o
In file included from /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/include/rtmp_os.h:42:0,
                 from /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/include/rtmp_comm.h:66,
                 from /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/include/rt_config.h:36,
                 from /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_cfg.c:28:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPAPSetInformation’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/include/os/rt_linux.h:466:56: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 #define RT_GET_OS_PID(_x, _y)  do { rcu_read_lock(); _x=(ULONG)current->pids[PIDTYPE_PID].pid; rcu_read_unlock(); } while(0)
                                                        ^
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/include/os/rt_linux.h:470:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘RT_GET_OS_PID’
 #define RTMP_GET_OS_PID(_a, _b)  RT_GET_OS_PID(_a, _b)
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_cfg.c:1901:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘RTMP_GET_OS_PID’
      RTMP_GET_OS_PID(pObj->IappPid, IappPid);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/include/os/rt_linux.h:466:56: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 #define RT_GET_OS_PID(_x, _y)  do { rcu_read_lock(); _x=(ULONG)current->pids[PIDTYPE_PID].pid; rcu_read_unlock(); } while(0)
                                                        ^
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/include/os/rt_linux.h:470:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘RT_GET_OS_PID’
 #define RTMP_GET_OS_PID(_a, _b)  RT_GET_OS_PID(_a, _b)
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_cfg.c:1918:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘RTMP_GET_OS_PID’
      RTMP_GET_OS_PID(pObj->apd_pid, apd_pid);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_cfg.c: In function ‘Set_IappPID_Proc’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/include/os/rt_linux.h:466:56: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 #define RT_GET_OS_PID(_x, _y)  do { rcu_read_lock(); _x=(ULONG)current->pids[PIDTYPE_PID].pid; rcu_read_unlock(); } while(0)
                                                        ^
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/include/os/rt_linux.h:470:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘RT_GET_OS_PID’
 #define RTMP_GET_OS_PID(_a, _b)  RT_GET_OS_PID(_a, _b)
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_cfg.c:9786:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘RTMP_GET_OS_PID’
  RTMP_GET_OS_PID(pObj->IappPid, IappPid);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPAPQueryInformation’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_cfg.c:3645:4: warning: ignoring return value of ‘copy_to_user’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
    copy_to_user(wrq->u.data.pointer, pMbssStat, wrq->u.data.length);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/crypt_md5.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/crypt_sha2.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/crypt_hmac.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/crypt_arc4.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wep.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/action.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.c: In function ‘NICInitializeAsic’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.c:1560:1: warning: the frame size of 1032 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
 }
 ^
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init_inf.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_tkip.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_aes.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_sync.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/eeprom.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_sanity.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c: In function ‘GetEncryptType’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:1756:5: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     if(enc == Ndis802_11Encryption3Enabled)
     ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:1758:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘if’
  if(enc == Ndis802_11Encryption4Enabled)
  ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c: In function ‘GetAuthMode’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:1772:5: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     if(auth == Ndis802_11AuthModeShared)
     ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:1774:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘if’
  if(auth == Ndis802_11AuthModeAutoSwitch)
  ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:1784:5: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     if(auth == Ndis802_11AuthModeWPA2PSK)
     ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:1786:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘if’
  if(auth == Ndis802_11AuthModeWPA1WPA2)
  ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c: In function ‘Show_PMK_Proc’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:4426:5: warning: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     for (idx = 0; idx < 32; idx++)
     ^~~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:4429:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘for’
  return 0;
  ^~~~~~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wpa.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wpa.c: In function ‘RTMPCheckWPAframe_Hdr_Trns’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wpa.c:3081:5: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     if(DataByteCount < (LENGTH_802_3 + LENGTH_EAPOL_H))
     ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wpa.c:3087:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the  ‘if’
  pData += LENGTH_802_3;
  ^~~~~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_radar.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/spectrum.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_timer.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rt_channel.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_profile.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_asic.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/scan.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/uapsd.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/ps.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../rate_ctrl/ra_ctrl.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../rate_ctrl/alg_legacy.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../rate_ctrl/alg_ags.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../chips/rtmp_chip.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/txpower.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mac/rtmp_mac.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mgmt/mgmt_hw.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mgmt/mgmt_entrytb.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mgmt/mgmt_entrytb.c: In function ‘MacTableInsertEntry’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mgmt/mgmt_entrytb.c:80:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if (pAd->MacTab.Size >= MAX_LEN_OF_MAC_TABLE)
  ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mgmt/mgmt_entrytb.c:83:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘if’
   FirstWcid = 1;
   ^~~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../phy/rtmp_phy.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../phy/rlt_phy.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../phy/rlt_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/netif_block.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../rate_ctrl/alg_grp.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/ba_action.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mgmt/mgmt_ht.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mcu/rtmp_and.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_mbss_inf.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rt_os_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../os/linux/ap_ioctl.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_main_dev.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_dls.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_dls.c: In function ‘APPeerDlsTearDownAction’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_dls.c:310:5: warning: this ‘if ’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     if (!pSAEntry)
     ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../ap/ap_dls.c:313:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘if’
  pDAEntry = MacTableLookup(pAd, DA);
  ^~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_usb.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data_usb.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data_usb.c: In function ‘ComposeNullFrame’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data_usb.c:210:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
  PTX_CONTEXT pNullContext = &pAd->NullContext[0];
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtusb_io.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtusb_io.c: In function ‘RTUSBEnqueueCmdFromNdis’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtusb_io.c:821:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if ((status != NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS) || (cmdqelmt == NULL))
  ^~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtusb_io.c:824:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the  ‘if’
   cmdqelmt->buffer = NULL;
   ^~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtusb_data.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtusb_bulk.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/ee_prom.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/ee_efuse.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/ee_efuse.c: In function ‘rtmp_ee_efuse_write16’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/ee_efuse.c:1463:5: warning: this ‘else’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     else
     ^~~~
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/ee_efuse.c:1465:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the ‘else’
  return 0;
  ^~~~~~
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mcu/rtmp_mcu.o
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mcu/rtmp_mcu.c: In function ‘MCUBurstWrite’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mcu/rtmp_mcu.c:34:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mcu/rtmp_mcu.c: In function ‘MCURandomWrite’:
/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mcu/rtmp_mcu.c:42:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mcu/rtmp_M51.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rt_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../chips/mt7601.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../mac/ral_omac.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../os/linux/usb_main_dev.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/rtusb_dev_id.o
  CC [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/../../common/frq_cal.o
  LD [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/mt7601Uap.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/mt7601Uap.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux/mt7601Uap.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.34-v7+'
pi@raspberrypi:~/mt7601u-ap-master $ sudo make install
make -C /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux'
mkdir -p /etc/wifi/RT2870AP
cp /home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/RT2870AP.txt /etc/wifi/RT2870AP/
install -m 644 -c mt7601Uap.ko /lib/modules/4.14.34-v7+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
depmod 4.14.34-v7+
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/mt7601u-ap-master/os/linux'
```

Comment: ビルド環境の件ですが、  
｢raspberrypi-kernel-headers｣をインストールすることで解決することが出来ました。  
しかしエラーが発生してしまいました。  
ログは上に追記しておきます。

Comment: このコンパイルエラーはなんとかなりますが、その後には更に難解なコンパイルエラーが控えています。開発者に問い合わせた方がよろしいかと。

Comment: これ関係してるかもしれません。=> https://github.com/tanaka1892/mt7601u-ap/issues/3

Comment: tanalab2さん、本当にありがとうございました。
/os/linux/config.mkにそれを記入することでコンパイルできました。
本当に感謝しています!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/lib/modules/4.14.50-v7+/build` が存在しないのは、おそらく kernel module のビルド環境をインストールしていないからだと思います。

使っている OS に kernel module ビルド環境のパッケージがあるはずですので、それをインストールしてください。Raspbian であれば、README.md に書いてある通りでできると思います。

https://github.com/tanaka1892/mt7601u-ap/blob/cd5058a778514b4ffb35be1afa6d359796316e32/README.md :

> Get the sources for your kernel. You can do this by running:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
> ```

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージのところ

> make -C /lib/modules/4.14.50-v7+/build SUBDIRS=/home/pi/mt7601u-ap/os/linux modules
>   make[1]: * /lib/modules/4.14.50-v7+/build: No such file or directory. Stop.

1行目は、torisoboroさんが入力したコマンド。
その内容は、makeコマンドに-Cオプション(makeの動作を始めるにあたって、指定されたディレクトリに移動する）が使われていて、移動先として　/lib/modules/4.14.50-v7+/build　が指定されています。

しかし、/lib/modules/4.14.50-v7+/buildというディレクトリが存在しないので"No such file or directory"というエラーが出力されただけで終わっています。

問題は、/lib/modules/4.14.50-v7+/buildという存在しないディレクトリを指定した事です。
正しいディレクトリを指定すれば、makeが正しく動作するのではないかと思われます。